# Using multiple conditions in np.where to update a column refrencing another column in the dataframe

Tags: python, numpy

I have a dataframe:

```
data = {'x' : [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3], 'y' : [1,4,5,2,6,7,8,3,9,10,11,12,13], 'z': [1,1,1,2,2,6,7,3,3,9,10,3,12], 'a': ['Parent', 'Node','Node', 'Parent', 'Node','Node','Node','Parent','Standalone', 'Node','Node','Node','Node']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Column:

- x represents ids of the parent;
- y represents individual ids of the parent, standalones and nodes;
- z represents ids under the group which it should fall

My object is to update column `z` where `z != x` and value of nodes should be aligned either to its parent or standalone.
The output column should look like `output = [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,9,9,3,3]`

I am trying to use the below code:

```
df.z = np.where((df.z.values != df.x.values) & (df.a != 'Standalone'), df[df['y'] == df.z.values]['z'], df.z.values)
```

but i am receiving this error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (13,) (3,) (13,)
```

Any lead on this would be helpful. Also, open to use .apply method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tricky part is Standalone, So groupby `x` to focus on each group, then define a function `do_by_check_standalone` to `gp.apply` to check if 'Standalone' in `gpdf.a`:

```
def do_by_check_standalone(df):
    if df['a'].isin(['Standalone']).any(): # need process
        #track Standalone's all childrens
        track_parent = {i: set([i]) for i in df[df['a'] == 'Standalone']['y']}
        for k in track_parent:
            #find all child
            s_len = -1
            e_len = 0
            while s_len != e_len:
                s_len = e_len
                track_parent[k].update(list(df[df['z'].isin(track_parent[k])]['y']))
                e_len = len(track_parent[k])
        # track_parent should be: {9: {9, 10, 11}}

        # loop each row
        for idx, row in df.iterrows():
            if row['a'] == 'Node': # child, need find its parent is 'Parent' or 'Standalone'
                isStandalone = False
                # if detects parent is 'Standalone', assign value of Standalone (e.g. k)
                for k in track_parent:
                    if row['z'] in track_parent[k]:
                        df.loc[idx, 'output'] = k
                        isStandalone = True
                        break
                if not isStandalone: # otherwise, set to 'x' (e.g. df.name which we groupby)
                    df.loc[idx, 'output'] = df.name
            else: # Parent or Standalone, simply fill 'x'
                df.loc[idx, 'output'] = df.name
    else: # no Standalone here, simply fill 'x'
        df.loc[:,'output'] = df.name # x
    
    return df
```

The `df.output` should fit your need (with some type convertion).

```
>>>df.groupby('x').apply(do_by_check_standalone)
    x   y   z   a   output
0   1   1   1   Parent  1.0
1   1   4   1   Node    1.0
2   1   5   1   Node    1.0
3   2   2   2   Parent  2.0
4   2   6   2   Node    2.0
5   2   7   6   Node    2.0
6   2   8   7   Node    2.0
7   3   3   3   Parent  3.0
8   3   9   3   Standalone  3.0
9   3   10  9   Node    9.0
10  3   11  10  Node    9.0
11  3   12  3   Node    3.0
12  3   13  12  Node    3.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped. Just out of curiosity can this be solved through np.where. I am dealing with 2.3m records. So trying to make the code as fast as possible.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it needs a lookup method recursively for `Standalone` and its `Node`. Need more info about the dataframe or I think it cannot be solved by only using `np.where`.